# Cannot import ThreadSensitiveContext from asgiref.sync, Upgrading django to 4.0

Tags: python, django

I am currently upgrading a django site from 3.0 to 4.0. I am looking at the error messages and try to fix them. One of the errors I got now was that I cannot import ThreadSensitiveContext from asgiref.sync. This was not an issue in Django 3 and I have not updated the asgiref library. Also since I took over this project, I am not sure what it is used for. Have anyone experienced the same problem?

Comment: Are you running the minimum Python and `asgiref` versions? Django 4.0 requires Python 3.8 and `asgiref` 3.4.1. Source: Django 4.0 release notes.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Django version, I found that I had the right Python version, but not a minimum version of Django.